# How do I correctly use a ReadLine statement to assign values to string Variables and then to array variables from a .txt file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a txt file with one column and 16 rows. I want to read them in a set of 4 values to string variables and then to array variables to be able to display them and do some calculations one after the other after clicking the next event.

Below is my code which displays the first set of values and the error 'file does not exist' pop up simultaneously:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim iFirstName(3) As String
    Dim LastName As String
    Dim iLastName(3) As String
    Dim EmployeeNumber As String
    Dim iEmployeeNumber(3) As String
    Dim HoursWorked As Decimal
    Dim PayRate As Decimal
    Dim iPayRate() As Decimal
    Dim PayRateString As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FirstNameButton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
        Dim Count As Integer
        Try
            Dim EmployeeStreamReader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\ademb\OneDrive\Desktop\Employee.txt")
            Do While EmployeeStreamReader.Peek <> -1
                FirstName = FirstName & EmployeeStreamReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
                LastName = LastName & EmployeeStreamReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
                EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber & EmployeeStreamReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
                PayRateString = PayRateString & EmployeeStreamReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            Loop

            FirstNameButton.Text = FirstName

            LastNameButton.Text = LastName

            EmployeeNumberButton.Text = EmployeeNumber
            PayRateButton.Text = PayRateString
            PayRate = Decimal.Parse(PayRateString)
            For Count = 0 To 3
                iFirstName(Count) = FirstName
                FirstNameButton.Text = iFirstName(Count)
                iLastName(Count) = LastName
                LastNameButton.Text = iLastName(Count)
                iEmployeeNumber(Count) = EmployeeNumber
                EmployeeNumberButton.Text = iEmployeeNumber(Count)
                iPayRate(Count) = PayRate
                PayRateButton.Text = iPayRate(Count)

            Next Count

        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FindPayButton.Click
        Try
            HoursWorked = Decimal.Parse(HoursWorkedTextBox.Text)
            If HoursWorked <= 40 Then
                PayButton.Text = (HoursWorked * PayRate).ToString
            Else
                PayButton.Text = ((HoursWorked * PayRate) + ((HoursWorked - 40) * PayRate * 1.5)).ToString
            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect entry")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: First things first, please read the description of a tag before applying it to your question. The VBA and VB.NET tags make it clear that they are different languages and should not be used for the other. You waste people's time when you spam tags.

Comment: Secondly, don't post irrelevant code as it makes it harder for us to focus on what is relevant. We don't need to see an empty `Click` event handler or one that just closes the form when the problem is reading a file. We only need to see code relevant to the reading of the file. Again, you waste people's time if you make them wade through code to determine what is relevant first, before they can even consider the problem.

Comment: The way you are doing this is not the way that any experienced developer would do it. Are you required to use those separate arrays as part of an assignment or are you just choosing to do it that way? If the latter, you should choose to do it the proper way, by defining a class with four properties and creating a list of instances of that class.

Comment: The way you're doing it now, you would end up with your `Buttons` showing all four first names at the same time, all four last names at the same time, etc. It seems to me that you should get rid of those four individual variables and just read the data straight into the arrays. You then keep track of the current record with an `Integer` variable that is an index into the arrays. To get the data for a single record, you use the same index to get an element from each array.

Comment: You also never actually create your `iPayRate` array.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer your question succinctly because your code is a mess and there are a number of things that need fixing. Here's a quick example of how you might read such a file into concurrent arrays and traverse the data. It demonstrates principles that you should be able to understand and apply to your own situation, which is what programming is all about.

```vb
Private Const UPPER_BOUND As Integer = 3

Private ReadOnly givenNames(UPPER_BOUND) As String
Private ReadOnly familyNames(UPPER_BOUND) As String
Private ReadOnly employeeNumbers(UPPER_BOUND) As String
Private ReadOnly payRates(UPPER_BOUND) As Decimal

Private recordIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using reader As New StreamReader("file path here")
        For i = 0 To UPPER_BOUND
            givenNames(i) = reader.ReadLine()
            familyNames(i) = reader.ReadLine()
            employeeNumbers(i) = reader.ReadLine()
            payRates(i) = CDec(reader.ReadLine())
        Next
    End Using

    DisplayCurrentRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub previousButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles previousButton.Click
    recordIndex -= 1

    previousButton.Enabled = recordIndex > 0
    nextButton.Enabled = True

    DisplayCurrentRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub nextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextButton.Click
    recordIndex += 1

    previousButton.Enabled = True
    nextButton.Enabled = recordIndex < UPPER_BOUND

    DisplayCurrentRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayCurrentRecord()
    givenNameLabel.Text = givenNames(recordIndex)
    familyNameLabel.Text = familyNames(recordIndex)
    employeeNumberLabel.Text = employeeNumbers(recordIndex)
    payRateLabel.Text = payRates(recordIndex).ToString("c")
End Sub
```